# Google Fusion Tables API - How to copy and rename a table?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have an existing fusion table with a certain format and I have a number of charts added to it. 
Idea is to make a copy, rename it and import additional rows into it. 
When I do the copy, there doesn't seem a way to specify what the name of new table should be. 
So I am assuming there must be a way to rename the table (since it is called Copy of ... by default). 
What is the right way to rename?

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need to do this using the google Fusion tables API. I know how to do this on Fusion tables UI. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File->About this table**. A window will appear, on the bottom of this window you'll find a link **"Edit Table information"**, that's where you may set different properties of the table, e.g. the name.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the title and change it in the dialog that pops up.